# If I set position:fixed for sidebar, icons disappear

Tags: css, sass

this is css for side-nav

```
.side-nav {
  // position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  width: calc(3.5vw + 3.5vh);
  // position: fixed;
  &.content {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: map-get($background-colors, side-nav);
    &.logo {
      img {
        width: calc(3.5vw + 3.5vh);
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    }
    &.icons {
      // object-fit: cover;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 2.2rem;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      &.github {
        svg {
          height: 4rem !important;
          width: 4rem !important;
          background-color: map-get($icon-bg-colors, github);
          color: map-get($icon-colors, github);
          border-radius: 50%;
          &:hover {
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
          }
        }
      }
      &.linkedin {
        svg {
          height: 4rem !important;
          width: 4rem !important;
          background-color: map-get($icon-bg-colors, linkedin);
          color: map-get($icon-colors, linkedin);
          border-radius: 10%;
          &:hover {
            color: rgb(25, 25, 109);
          }
        }
      }

      &.stackoverflow {
        svg {
          height: 4rem !important;
          width: 4rem !important;
          // color: rgb(235, 152, 0);
          color: map-get($icon-colors, stackoverflow);
          &:hover {
            background-color: white;
          }
          &:active {
            color: red;
          }
        }
      }
      &.twitter {
        svg {
          height: 4rem !important;
          width: 4rem !important;
          // color: rgb(235, 152, 0);
          color: map-get($icon-colors, twitter);
          &:hover {
            background-color: white;
          }
          &:active {
            color: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if position is NOT fixed this is how it looks

[image]

If I change only the `position:fixed`, this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: try to add `z-index:10` to your `.icons` class

Comment: @DaddysCode it did not work

Comment: increase the amount like `z-index:500`

Answer (score 0):

it turns out if you use `overflow-x:hidden`, it was conflicting with the `position:fixed`. I was using `overflow-x:hidden` in body element. I removed and it works again